# Change in 'hosts' file responds to ping but refuses to connect on any browser

Tags: windows-10, networking, browser, ping, hosts-file

I'm currently working on a project where I need to emulate the live site's URL's in order to properly communicate between the projects site, projects browser extension, and the projects database. To do this, I modified my computers 'hosts' file. It took my a few hours to resolve any issues I had with it initially, and it was working for about 2 weeks. Yesterday, it stopped working again and I've not had any luck at all with getting it working again. I did not change anything in my hosts files.

Also, navigating to `localhost:3080`, `127.0.0.1:3080` or even `example-site.com:3080` in the browser works properly but not simply `example-site.com` - this was working recently.

I've looked through **MANY** *superuser.com* and *stackoverflow.com* posts and answers where people are experiencing similar issues and I've had no luck in implementing any solution.

Here's what my hosts file looks like:

```
...
127.0.0.1     example-site.com www.example-site.com
...
```

I've also tried separating the entries on to different lines but it's made no difference.

Pinging the URL works from what I understand as well. Below is the ping response:

```
Pinging example-site.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Some of the things I've tried:

- Restarting computer (several times)
- `ipconfig /flushdns` in Terminal with administrative privileges
- Clearing host cache in Chrome (`chrome://net-internals/#dns`)
- Allowing invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost (`chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`)
- Running `sfc /scannow` in terminal
- Made sure hosts file was encoded in ANSI or UTF-8
- Several other things that I can't recall...

Any help or insight that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `hosts`-file isn't relevant to the issue, it only binds names to IP addresses. `localhost:3080` and `example-site.com:3080` being reachable with a browser but simple `example-site.com` not means the service is not accepting traffic in ports 80 (HTTP) and/or 443 (HTTPS). You can check this running `netstat -aon` in elevated command prompt. If for example port 80 is open you'll see `0.0.0.0:80 LISTENING`. If you don't, check the configs and verify firewall's not blocking the traffic.

Comment: I don't think you can do that if you are connected to the internet.  Any requests are routed through Domain Name Servers.  If it was easily possible we would all be running microsoft.com on our machines.  Not my area of expertise, but perhaps you can mimic a DNS and point your settings to that.

Comment: @RohitGupta The Windows networking stack checks the hosts file first, then DNS. Otherwise you’d never be able to resolve `localhost` since that hostname is explicitly disallowed to be resolved in DNS.

Comment: @Peregrino69 - thank you for the response! I ran the netstat command and I do not see `0.0.0.0:80` or `0.0.0.0:443` as `LISTENING` ports. I do see `0.0.0.0:3080` as well as `0.0.0.0:3443` (ports my project is running on). So, I looked at my firewall and turned it off completely. I am not sure what you mean about checking the configs though - could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: You don't describe the project itself, but since you're using browser to access, there must be a running service that provides HTTP/HTTPS access to it. The server configuration file contains something along the lines of `listen-port=3080`. You may be able to add also ports 80 and 443 to the config, depending on which protocol you want to use. Most modern web services allow only HTTPS access, i.e. port 443. If you get that done and able to access with firewall off but not when it's on, you need to allow access on the ports also in the firewall configuration.

Comment: @Peregrino69 yep, that was it. I changed the server ports in my projects configs from 3080 and 3443 to 80 and 443 respectively. That did the trick. Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Thanks for letting me know. I put the comments into an answer, please do accept it so this doesn't pop up later down the line as "Unanaswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hosts`-file isn't relevant to the issue, it only binds names to IP addresses.

As `localhost:3080` and `example-site.com:3080` are reachable with a browser but simple `example-site.com` isn't, the web service is not accepting traffic in ports 80 (HTTP) and/or 443 (HTTPS). This can be verified on Windows OS by running `netstat -aon` in elevated command prompt. If the ports are open, `netstat` will show `0.0.0.0:80 LISTENING` and `0.0.0.0:443 LISTENING`.

If these aren't showing, the service providing the access isn't listening on these ports. The current service configuration file will contain two entries along the lines of `listen-port=3080` and `listen-port=3443`. It should be possible to simply add ports 80 and 443 the same way, depending on the protocol access should be allowed on. Modern web services usually only allow HTTPS.

If adding these ports in the config enables access with the firewall off but not when it's turned on, the same ports need to be opened also in the firewall configuration.

With *NIX OS `netstat` command and output are a bit different. In Debian Bullseye I'd use command `netstat -tulpn | grep "80\|443" | grep "LISTEN"`.